# how to convert timedelta which is in days into string?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have taken difference between current week start and date week start where date is column of dates. This difference is in days. When I am trying to define function to convert these days into 1 week difference, 2 week difference and so on.

I am getting error as:

> Cannot compare type 'Timedelta' with type 'str'

Please help me to resolve this. I am worry about am I wrong, in defining function?  here is the code which defining function:

```
def check(diff):
    for d in final_data['diff']:
        if  ((d > '0 days') and (d <= '7 days')): 
            weekdiff = 'OneWeekDiff'
        elif ((d > '8 days') and (d <= '14 days')):
            weekdiff = 'TwoWeekDiff'
        else:       
            weekdiff = 'Current Week'
    return weekdiff
```

To find out difference between two columns, simply I have subtraction like this:
final_data['diff'] = final_data['CurrentWeekStartDay'] - final_data['InvoiceWeekstartDay']

print(final_data['diff']
0       14 days
1       14 days
2       14 days

Comment: final_data['diff'] can you print this and attached to the question

Comment: Hi I have added 'diff' coloumn. I used your code but still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) strings `0 days`, `7 days`...:

Then I little bit modify function - remove loop and `else`. You can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) function for column of `DataFrame`:

```
def check(d):
    weekdiff = 'Current Week'
    if  ((d > pd.to_timedelta('0 days')) and (d <= pd.to_timedelta('7 days'))): 
        weekdiff = 'OneWeekDiff'
    elif ((d > pd.to_timedelta('8 days')) and (d <= pd.to_timedelta('14 days'))):
        weekdiff = 'TwoWeekDiff'
    return weekdiff

print (final_data['diff'].apply(check))
```

Sample:

```
final_data = pd.DataFrame({'b': {0: pd.Timestamp('2016-01-13 00:00:00'), 
                                 1: pd.Timestamp('2016-01-05 00:00:00'), 
                                 2: pd.Timestamp('2016-01-03 00:00:00')}, 
                            'a': {0: pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), 
                                  1: pd.Timestamp('2016-01-02 00:00:00'), 
                                  2: pd.Timestamp('2016-01-03 00:00:00')}, 
                            'diff': {0: pd.Timedelta('12 days 00:00:00'), 
                                     1: pd.Timedelta('3 days 00:00:00'), 
                                     2: pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')}})
print (final_data)
           a          b    diff
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-13 12 days
1 2016-01-02 2016-01-05  3 days
2 2016-01-03 2016-01-03  0 days

print (final_data['diff'].apply(check))
0     TwoWeekDiff
1     OneWeekDiff
2    Current Week
Name: diff, dtype: object
```